# не могу разобраться почему мой код отрабатывает не совсем корректно

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, filter

мне нужно с помощью filter перебрать вложенные массивы и вывести в консоль только те, в которых есть число 3

Сам код, в целом работает, т.е в консоль выводятся нужные массивы, но каждый выводится по 3 раза

```
let b10 = [ [1,2,3], [3,4,6], [4,5,7], [8,9,3]]

function t10() {
    
    b10.filter(item =>{
        item.filter((elem, index, arr) =>{
            if (arr. includes(3)){
                console.log(arr)
            }
        })
    })
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = t10
```

Comment: Дополни условие `if( arr. includes(3) && index == arr.length-1)`

Comment: а второй фильтр точно нужен?

Comment: ну без второго фильтра я не знала как сделать

Comment: let b10 = [ [1,2,3], [3,4,6], [4,5,7], [8,9,3]]

function t10() {
    b10.filter(item => {
        if (item.includes(3)) {
            console.log(item)
        }
    })
}